# inherit `sameFunctionName<T>()` from 2 template classes ==> ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have `C<T>` that manage a specific primitive type, `T`.
I want to group all functions of `C<int>` and `C<float>` into `Utility` for my ease of usage.

```
template<typename T> class B{};
template<typename T> class C{
    public: static void foo(B<T> bt){} 
    /** complex implemention in .cpp (I use explicit instantiation) */
    /** a lot of functions!!!!!, each one with a lot of parameters */
};
class Utility: public C<int>,public C<float>{};
int main(){
    B<int> bInt;
    Utility::foo(bInt); //I don't want to change this line
}
```

[Coliru MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f29ab75ad2f89376)
I expect `Utility::foo(bInt)` to have same meaning as `C<int>::foo(bInt)`, but  I got this error :-

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:14: error: reference to 'foo' is ambiguous
    9 |     Utility::foo(bInt); //I don't want to change this line
      |              ^~~
main.cpp:3:25: note: candidates are: 'static void C<T>::foo(B<T>) [with T = float]'
    3 |     public: static void foo(B<T> bt){}
      |                         ^~~
main.cpp:3:25: note:                 'static void C<T>::foo(B<T>) [with T = int]'
```

I don't want to change how `foo` is called.
I like the way it is, except that it doesn't compile.
It looks like compiler fail to deduce and call a correct T-function.
How to fix the compile error?

Note that I have many functions inside `C`.
***cigien***'s solution works well, except that it can be tedious for my case.

Similar question : [Ambiguous multiple inheritance of template classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874029/ambiguous-multiple-inheritance-of-template-classes) (very tedious for my case)

Answer (score 2):

You can bring in the specific versions of `foo` that you need into `C`, like this:

```
class Utility : public C<int>, public C<float>
{
  public:
    using C<int>::foo;
    using C<float>::foo;
};
```

Now template argument deduction can deduce the right `foo` to call.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9bjcbT).

Comment: T_T.   There are a lot of functions inside C.    I don't want to do them all.

Comment: I think you'll have to do this for each of them.