# Why are members from multiple inheritances of same class template ambiguous?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, overload-resolution, template-argument-deduction

When inheriting from a class template multiple times, there is the problem that [multiple inheritance of these template classes makes member functions ambiguous](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/35874029/ambiguous-multiple-inheritance-of-template-classes) ([also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002663/inherit-samefunctionnamet-from-2-template-classes-ambiguous)), because apparently [it is defined that way in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874272/20255529).

**Question**: Why is this defined ambiguous?

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base
{
    T val;

public:
    Base(T val) : val(val) {}

    void print(T v)
    {
        std::cout << val << " " << v << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Base<int>, public Base<std::string>
{
public:
    Child() : Base<int>(0), Base<std::string>("0"){}

    // Necessary for successful compilation
//     using Base<int>::print;
//     using Base<std::string>::print;

};

int main()
{
    Child c;

    c.print(1);
    c.print(std::string("1"));
    
    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
error: request for member ‘print’ is ambiguous
   38 |     c.print(1);
      |       ^~~~~
   39 |     c.print(std::string("1"));
      |       ^~~~~
note: candidates are: ‘void Base<T>::print(T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
note:                 ‘void Base<T>::print(T) [with T = int]’
```

Instead of manually spelling out, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874315/20255529) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874315/20255529),

```cpp
using Base<int>::print;
using Base<std::string>::print;
```

I can just create a template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void print(T v)
{
    this->Base<T>::print(v);
}
```

I understand that with this template I tell the compiler in which base class to look, but I fail to understand why that would be necessary in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't the top answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874029/ambiguous-multiple-inheritance-of-template-classes) tell you why?

Comment: Overloading only applies to names that are defined in the same scope. Those two versions of `print` are defined in two different scopes: `Base<int>` and `Base<std::string>`, so they do not overload. Pulling them into `Child` with those `using` directives fixes the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, because this answer does not explain why it is ambiguous. Obviously the function name can be found in both base classes, but the function parameters are different. So I would assume that standard rules for resolving function overloading should make them unambiguous.

Comment: Name lookup only looks up the name, and the name is the same even if the signature is different.

Comment: BTW, you might simplify the problem with regular (non-template) bases. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EdjezKPYx)